# Customize the name displayed in the Tabs

Tags: vmware-workstation

In VMWare Workstation's UI, you get tabs that display the opened VM names.

Since I work a lot with snapshots, I'd like to display the snapshot name instead of the VM name.

Is that at all possible?

Thanks